# i18n + views, getting localized version of node

Tags: 7, views, nodes, i18n-l10n

I have a view, lets call this **View A**, which only shows nodes - that are referenced as the 'hero' node to a taxononmy (one to one relationship). Additionally, I have another view, lets call this **View B** which does the opposite: only shows those nodes that do not have the hero relationship with a taxonomy.

Now I have translated all these nodes with the i18n module into two languages. But when I change language on the site the following happens:

View A stays the same, only showing the content in its original languages (in the language of which the relationships were created).

View B has the same content as it had, plus the translated 'hero nodes' that are supposed to be in View A.

I kinda gather this has to do with the relationship of node ids that is being filtered. However, how can I make this work that both View A and View B will show the appropriate localized content?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your Filter Criteria: "Content: Language (= Current user's language)."